# Custom query variable - get wordpress to redirect to nice permalink url

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, meta-query, custom-post-type-archives

I have been looking for an answer for the last couple of hours but could not find anything pointing me in the right direction. Some advice would be very much appreciated!

- What I already have:

  - A custom post type `'stores'`
  - A public query var using the `'query_vars'` filter hook: `'state'`.
  - Added the according rewrite rule:

    - Pattern: `stores/state/([^/]+)/?$`
    - Match: `index.php?post_type=stores&state=$matches[1]`
  - As `'state'` is a custom meta field, I added a function hooking into `pre_get_posts` action hook doing all the query magic (creating `meta_query` etc) to display only the matching `stores` in the archive page.

That's all working quite well:

So if I enter `www.myurl.com/stores/state/austria` my archive page is only showing Austrian stores.

To filter the stores not only by url, the archive page includes a form to filter them. This is where I run into my problem: the form obviously only passes POST or GET data, e.g. like the following:

```
www.myurl.com/stores/?state=austria
```

I can deal with this by adding a check in my `pre_get_posts` filter function:

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['state'] ) || $query->get('state') != "" ) {
```

However, this is a little dirty as I would like wordpress to automatically redirect to the rewritten URL:

```
www.myurl.com/stores/?state=austria
```

should be redirected to

```
www.myurl.com/stores/state/austria
```

the same way it is done if I enter a page or post ID and it redirects to the permalink.

Is there another action hook I have not discovered yet? How would I get wordpress to automatically redirect to the pretty permalink?

Thank you for every hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution myself. No javascript required, only another template function. URL building done manually.

The idea is to use the hook 'template_redirect', check if the requested page is the corresponding store archive page, then check for $_REQUEST vars there and build a new URL. Finally redirect to this URL.

```
function my_template_redirect() {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'stores' ) ) {
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['state'] )  ) {
            $myurl = get_post_type_archive_link( 'stores' );
            if (substr($myurl, -1) != "/") $myurl .= "/";
            $myurl .= "state/";
            $myurl .= trim( sanitize_title_for_query( $_REQUEST['state'] ) ) . "/";
            exit( wp_redirect( $myurl ) ) ;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect' );
```

Works pretty well. Any corrections/better ideas are welcome of course.

Comment: Good. Just a tip `if (substr($myurl, -1) != "/") $myurl .= "/"; $myurl .= "state/";` can be written as `$myurl = trailingslashit($myurl) . '/state/'`. However +1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best solution, nor the solution you are looking for, but this comes in my mind now, someone can maybe give you another.

I think in the page form you have something like this:

```
<select name="state">
   <option value="austria">Austria</option>
   ...
</select>
```

Using javascript it's easy send user to the pretty url.

(I put javascript here, you ensure put it in a separate js file and enqueue it with `wp_enqueue_script`)

Untested:

```
jQuery().ready(function($) {
  $('select[name="state"]').change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var state = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '/' + state;
  });
});
```

Comment: It quite certainly will work, but to be honest I think this also is a rather dirty 'solution' for two reasons:

Comment: The 2 reasons? :) Yes, as I said in first sentence, is not a good solution. Every solution that require js are dirty ones in wp. It's just a workaround until someone will answer you better. I admit rewrite rules are not my favourite WP argument. If can be useful, in a theme I've developed with similar situation, I've used js to hide things (using `data-` attribute) when items already there and when I need to load I used ajax. For browser with no js I let form submit and show the filtered items via $_POST var. @mndmkr

Comment: I'm sorry, I hit the enter key too early. My apologies.

1) The page won't work without javascript enabled. However, I could put in a fallback that relies on the GET/POST string.
2) The javascript does not rely on the WP functions / query vars, it is hard-coded. Changing the query vars would result in a disfunctional javascript. Probably could work around that as well by putting the javascript together dynamically.

Ideally I would like a solution where the redirection and URL building is done by WP - as it is certainly capable of it.

But thank you for you input anyway!

Comment: @mndmkr For the 1) you get solution. For 2) you can pass the right redirect url via `wp_localize_script` and it will works. But.. again, I'm not *promoting* my answer, as already said is more a workaround than a really solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, G.M. I just a found a solution using another WP hook - maybe it will be useful for you too!